# Why am I suddenly hostile to the whole world?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I've been doing a Cathar world conquest, and suddenly all hell has broken loose. The entire world seems to be against me... in a weird way. I'm not in any war, everyone is just hostile for some reason. Here's my ruler's diplomacy screen/active wars:

[image: wars]

As you can see, I have a few truces, but a very large number of these yellow blips. When I click on one, it takes me to a completely random (as far as I can tell) duchy. I've gone from places in Russia to North Africa to India by clicking on them. My borders currently don't really extend east of Italy so there's no adjacency, and there's no rhyme or reason to the religion or culture of the pips (which I would expect if this meant I had, e.g., a Jihad or Crusade called on me). Hovering over them produces no tooltip text.

[image: enemies]

That's a picture of the Byzantine Empire (who I'm spying on) as you can see, I'm hostile to their armies, even though I'm not in any active war against them.

[image: sieges]

Here are some sieges, as you can see, I've completely sieged a province in Italy (upper right), despite there being no war. Some army I'm not hostile to partially sieged one of my provinces, which I can't siege back. I think it's a trade post that got sieged, though technically I own the trade port somehow.

[image: ledger]

Finally, there's the ledger, nothing out of the ordinary as far as I can see.

Recent notable events in my game:

1. This seemed to occur immediately after I killed the Italian king and got caught (so I could declare another Holy War without breaking my truce).
2. Cathar very recently displaced Catholocism as the main branch of the religion.
3. I had a holy war (as far as I can tell, a normal Holy War, not a Jihad) called on me by the Shi'a Caliph, which I crushed.
4. I think there are a few distant event-spawn host invasions, but that's really far east of me. It's currently 1064.

Can somebody explain what happened? I really have no idea what's going on and having tiny little 500 man armies failing to siege random things in my empire and generally slowing down my troops with fights I have no vested interest in is rather obnoxious. I should note that I can still declare wars as normal, and I can get warscore, siege, and enforce demands as normal. Nothing seems to have changed except the game made me hostile to everyone.

Comment: Reloading the game has fixed this bug the one time it occured for me before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a rather rare glitch, which can easily be fixed by fully restarting your game.

If you don't want to lose your current progress, you can save it normally and by the time you restart your game, it will look like nothing ever happened.